# ./vendor/bin/sail: line 42: docker-compose: command not found

Tags: php, linux, laravel, docker, backend

I'm trying to develop a Laravel 8 app using docker, I previously have installed docker 20.10.3 on my ubuntu 20 pc,  [I followed every step for Linux installation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#getting-started-on-linux) but, when I type **./vendor/bin/sail up** I get:

```
./vendor/bin/sail: line 42: docker-compose: command not found
./vendor/bin/sail: line 44: docker-compose: command not found
./vendor/bin/sail: line 280: docker-compose: command not found
```

I don't know what could be because everything went fine:
[image]

Comment: The instructions seem to assume you have docker installed. Maybe take a look at this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose-on-linux-systems

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you checked the sail on github for this line 42
https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/bin/sail
you will find that it's using docker-compose command , and looks like it's not installed on your machine. you can follow this link to install it https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-20-04
Then everything supposed to be working fine again

Comment: Thanks, I had not installed docker-compose. its work very well

Answer (score 6):

docker-compose is not installed to your system. To install it apply below command :

> sudo apt install docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

check [official docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) and add docker-compose in the installation, you will be fine and then it will upgrade docker-compose along with docker each time.